# How come the scientist in the second planet is not super old?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

When Cooper (McConaughey) and Brand (Hathaway) return from the ground of the first planet in *Interstellar*, the scientist (Romilly?) that stayed in the ship aged 23 years because of the effect of Gargantua, right?

So, when they traveled to the next planet and met Dr. Mann (Matt Damon), Dr. Mann did not age the same 23 years. He aged in the same rate as Brand and Cooper.

Everybody on earth aged 23 years, Romilly aged 23 years. So, why did Dr. Mann not age in the same rate?

I understand that as a plot inconsistency. Is there another explanation?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is an explanation for that. **Dr. Mann was in some kind of hypersleep.** This is apparently an established technology in the film. You can see Cooper and the rest of the Endurance crew enter hypersleep during their 2 years of travel from Earth to Saturn.

It is also mentioned that Romilly *could* have gone to hypersleep, too, but chose not to anymore at some point since he was unaware of when Cooper and Brand would return, which is why he did age significantly (even if maybe not the entire 23 years), and why Brand assumes that he didn't go to sleep.

> **Brand** (seeing old Romilly): Why didn't you sleep?
>   **Romilly:** Oh, I had a couple of stretches. But I stopped believing you were coming back. And something seemed wrong about dreaming my life away.

And later Dr. Mann also explains how he entered hypersleep waiting for someone to rescue him:

> My supplies were completely exhausted. The last time I went to sleep, I didn't even set a waking date. You have literally raised me from the dead.

Now of course it's unclear if that hypersleep is able to completely halt any aging at all, but given the science-fiction setting it's not a big stretch to accept that **it slows down aging to a large degree**.

Comment: Would make sense if hypersleep would stop aging, but it doesn't. It's just a plot device so them don't go crazy after running out of things to do for 2 years.

Comment: Also, I heard that the 3 planets are around Gargantua and that would make him age slow. I don't believe it's also true.

Comment: @vianna77 Well, we don't *know* if it does, it's magic future tech. Brand specifically asks Romilly why he didn't sleep after seeing how old he is, that certainly suggests a connection.

Comment: @vianna77 No. It is specifically clarified that *only* Miller's planet was near enough to Gargantua to have a significant effect on Cooper's and Brand's time. Mann's planet, as well as Romilly aboard the Endurance (who afterall was much closer to the black hole than Mann), never got near enough to be affected by it as much. For more information on that, see [this question and its answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/47271/49)

Comment: I agree with you! The other planets are not around Gargantua! That's one friend of mine trying to explain Mann not aging.

Comment: And "dreaming my life away" means exactly that he would age 23 years. Otherwise he would only wake 1 hour older from the sleep. My understand is that time pass normally in those capsules.

Comment: Yes, that comment could be interpreted that way indeed. But I would still assume the hypersleep at least *reduces* aging due to the other reasons mentioned.

Comment: @vianna77 I think you have to take the 'dreaming my life away' and the 'why didn't you sleep?' lines to show that hypersleep doesn't suspend aging entirely but does reduce it significantly.  I certainly don't view Mann's apparent lack of significant aging to be a plot hole at all.

Comment: @vianna77 Immediately before talking about "dreaming his life away" Romilly said "I stopped believing you were coming back."  Meaning he didn't think he was waiting 23 years anymore, he thought he was waiting to die, and he didn't want to to do it in hypersleep.  This is also more evidence that hypersleep only slows aging, doesn't stop it - ie: he *would have* died eventually if he kept sleeping until they came back (which he no longer believed they would.)